# Node.js: how to find a user in firebase Authentication by uid?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm fairly new to node and making a web-app in which I use passport to authenticate and then store the user using firebase authentication by a custom token.

and now i want to perform a lookup and check if the user is registered with my app.

So is there is a way to check for a specific user (like either by their uid or email)?

in the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users) it is given how to list all the users.

here is the code for it (i modified a bit for my purpose) -

```
function listAllUsers(id, nextPageToken) { // passing an id to check and page token is not passed as default
  // List batch of users, 1000 at a time.
  admin.auth().listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
    .then(function(listUsersResult) {
      listUsersResult.users.forEach(function(userRecord) {
        if (userRecord.uid == id){
              return true // here i return from the function but it only return from one function. (do i have to make a flag to come out from all of them?)
            }
      });
      if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {
        // List next batch of users.
        listAllUsers(id, listUsersResult.pageToken)
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error listing users:", error);
    });
}
// Start listing users from the beginning, 1000 at a time.
let user = listAllUsers('some random id'); // i expect a Boolean here
```

but is there any way to do a lookup like `listUsersResult.users.find(id) // which may return a boolean or whole user?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the docs you linked and having played around a little in firebase myself, there is no method that returns a found/not found boolean. However, you can do:

```
admin.auth().getUser(uid)
  .then(function(userRecord) {
       // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
       console.log("Successfully fetched user data:", userRecord.toJSON());
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error fetching user data:", error);
  });
```

As quoted by their docs:

> If the provided `uid` does not belong to an existing user or the user cannot be fetched for any other reason, the above method throws an error.

If you want a boolean simply set a boolean in the `then...catch` to whether the user was found or not.

For example:

```
let found = false;

admin.auth().getUser(uid)
  .then(function(userRecord) {
      found = true;
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
      found = false;
  });
```

**EDIT**

To return to your base function, the best way (in terms of Node) is to make the function asynchronous with a callback/Promise/Observable. As Promise's are newer I will create one here:

```
var user_check = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    admin.auth().getUser(uid)
      .then(function(userRecord) {
          resolve(userRecord);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
          reject(error);
      });
});
console.log(user_check); // if found, returns the user_record, else, returns an error
```

For more information regarding async code, refer to [MSDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: thanks for the answer but for some reason i always returns false when i use arrow function for this `const user_check = (id) => {

    let verify = false;
    firebase.auth().getUser(id).then(function (userRecord) {

        verify = userRecord;
        console.log('yes');

    }).catch(function (error) {

        verify = false;
    });
    return verify
};
` 
any guesses why it always returns false? i even did a console log and it does gets called.

Comment: How are you checking the value of `verify`? `console.log()`? The way you have written it, `verify` will be an object and not a boolean unless you double bang (`!!`) it.

Comment: actually instead of returning a boolean now what i'm doing is that if the user exist it returns the user else return false. but when i return anything it only returns from the `admin.auth()` funciton how to return from my `check_user ` function, should i take a flag?

Comment: Ah yes how silly of me! The probably best way to return from `user_check` is to make it an asynchronous call (i.e. Promise/callback/Observable). I will add to my answer

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data).  You can call `admin.auth.getUser(uid)` for this (also [see the API docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#getUser)).